# Why do we name variables in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In some of the places, I saw the syntax, where variables are initialized with names, sometimes without names. For example:

```
# With name
var = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")

# Without
one = tf.constant(1)
```

What is the point of naming the variable `var` `"counter"`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `name` parameter is optional (you can create variables and constants with or without it), and the variable you use in your program does not depend on it. Names can be helpful in a couple of places:

**When you want to save or restore your variables** (you can [save them to a binary file](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops.md#Saver) after the computation). From [docs](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/index.md):

> By default, it uses the value of the Variable.name property for each
>   variable

```
matrix_1 = tf.Variable([[1, 2], [2, 3]], name="v1")
matrix_2 = tf.Variable([[3, 4], [5, 6]], name="v2")
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
save_path = saver.save(sess, "/model.ckpt")
sess.close()
```

Nonetheless you have variables `matrix_1`, `matrix_2` they are saves as `v1`, `v2` in the file.

**Also names are used in TensorBoard to nicely show names of edges**. You can even [group them by using the same scope](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/graph_viz/index.md#name_scoping_and_nodes):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope('hidden') as scope:
  a = tf.constant(5, name='alpha')
  W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1, 2], -1.0, 1.0), name='weights')
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='biases')
```

Comment: I'd like to note, Martin Garrix copied this code to use as part of his visuals for a live set: https://www.reddit.com/r/Martingarrix/comments/cekwfw/martin_garrix_copies_stack_overflow_code_for_his/

Answer (score 18):

You can imagine Python namespace and TensorFlow namespace as two parallel universes. Names in TensorFlow space are actually the "real" attributes belonging to any TensorFlow variables, while names in Python space are just temporary pointers pointing to TensorFlow variables during this run of your script. That is the reason why when saving and restoring variables, only TensorFlow names are used, because the Python namespace no longer exists after script being terminated, but Tensorflow namespace is still there in your saved files.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following use case code and its output

```
def f():
    a = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(), dtype = tf.float32, name = 'test123')

def run123():
    f()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess123:
        sess123.run(init)
        print(sess123.run(fetches = ['test123:0']))
        print(sess123.run(fetches = [a]))

run123()
```

output:

> [0.10108799]
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        10         print(sess123.run(fetches = [a]))
>        11 
>   ---> 12 run123()
>
> in run123()
>         8         sess123.run(init)
>         9         print(sess123.run(fetches = ['test123:0']))
>   ---> 10         print(sess123.run(fetches = [a]))
>        11 
>        12 run123()
>
> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

The 'a', as defined in the scope of f(), not available outside of its scope, i.e in run123(). But the default graph has to refer to them with something, so that the default graph can be referenced to, as needed, across various scopes and that is when its **name** comes handy.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, from the aspect to distinguish different variables, we totally can use the python name (the left part of the assignment sign, and we call the name as `python name` to avoid confusion. such as `v` in the following example) to name the variables. However, in the programming process, we usually rebind the python name to other objects (i.e., the op in Tensorflow), for example,

```
v = tf.get_variable("v1", [3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v = tf.get_variable("v2", [5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
```

Firstly, the python name `v` bind the tensor form first line (`tf.get_variable("v1", [3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)`). Then,the `v` rebind the tensor from the second line (`tf.get_variable("v2", [5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer`)) and didn't bind the first tensor anymore. If we didn't give the tensorflow attribute name `v1` and `v2`, how can we identify the tensor from the first line?