# What's the difference of two tensorflow variable names?

Tags: tensorflow

A new beginner of tensorflow and a simple question is:
I saw a code:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zero((2,2)),name="weights")
```

What is the different with "W1" and "weights"?

Answer (score 3):

In short, `weights` is the unique name of the variable in the Tensorflow graph, and `W1` is the name of the python variable pointing to the Tensorflow variable. If you then assign `W1` to a new variable; e.g `W2 = W1`, you'll see that the name of `W2` is also `weights`; different python names (and variables), same Tensorflow name (and variable).

Naming a new variable with `name='weights'` will actually create a variable with the name `weights_1:0` :

```
>>> tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2,2)), name="weights")
<tf.Variable 'weights_1:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Comment: Thx, would you mind talk a little more about tensorflow variable and python variable? Because I saw some codes online and the variable should be run in the session, and in session, they are using sess.run(W1), so this is using python variable (W1), but where and how to use tensorflow variable (weights)?

Comment: The python variable is merely a "pointer" to the tensorflow variable, but using them is still the only way to manipulate tensorflow variables. sess.run(W1) is ran in the tensorflow graph in any case

Answer (score 1):

`W1` is the name of the python variable. It is intended for a python interpreter you will use it to address this variable in your code. So if you will need to do some operations (add, multiply, conv, initialize), you will use this name. You can think about it as a pointer which knows where is the location of your tensor.

`name='weights'` is intended for a human. For a more detailed answer look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33648339/1090562). When you will print the python variable you will see this name. It is also used to save/restore the variables and for visualization in [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz):

[image]