# How does TensorFlow implement registering variables in one point in the code and then initializing it at another place?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement a similar if not identical behaviour that TensorFlow has.

So say one does:

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
... #some code
x_val = x.eval() # maybe very far away from x, could be inside some function
```

I was wondering how tensorflow implemented that sort of code. How does one essentially register variables to a module that was imported at the top (in this example something like `tf`) and then able to modify it or manipulate it later? Does the `tf` module update some internal global variables inside of the tensorflow library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically which technology they use for implementing them. But Tensorflow use a tree-like namespace for `Tensor`s and `Variable`s (with variables have some peculiarities). So, `Tensor` objects hold this, let's say, identifier that then will be used for serializing the tensor (losing any dependency with python variables). As a matter of fact, you are not allowed to assign the same `name` parameter at two different tensors inside the same `name_scope`.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648167/why-do-we-use-name-parameter-when-creating-a-variable-in-tensorflow) answer